# Download on iPhone Caching?

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection

I felt like I'm having the same issues as addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405151/is-it-possible-to-prevent-an-nsurlrequest-from-caching-data-or-remove-cached-data/405896#405896).  But everything I try doesn't seem to work.

The program goes as follows:

- I'm asking for user credentials (username/password)
- Then I do some calls to the server downloading information.
- When its finished, I display a set of users, the user clicks on one, then is asked for the password for that account
- I then make another request to the server and check to see if I get the right information back (therefore verifying the username/password just given is correct)

The problem is, the last call is similar (same url, different credentials) to one that I do in the initial download.  Regardless of what the user puts in for the second credentials the "correct" information comes back.  I think this is because it is caching the response, but I can't figure out how to stop it from doing that.

I'm have a class that makes the connection and returns the downloaded data.  And I make a new class for every connection.  So I'm not really sure why its saving data.

I have a NSMutableURLRequest in which I do the following:

```
 [theRequest setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
```

(I have also tried, `NSURLRequestReloadRevalidatingCacheData` and `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData`)

I've also implemnted the functions:

```
- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection   
                  willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse {
return nil;
}

- (BOOL)connectionShouldUseCredentialStorage:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
return NO;
}
```

With the last one I don't fully understand it.  So I tired YES and NO. And I've tried various NSURLRequest cache policies.

Any help on what my issue might be would be very helpful.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess, but would using

```
NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
```

rather than

> NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData

make any difference?

Comment: I didn't even know that existed, but no, it didn't work.  Any more ideas?

Comment: What about NSHTTPCookieStorage? Try deleting the cookies for the URL, before the second request, or setting [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedStorage] setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyNever]

Comment: Thank you!!  I used [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyNever]; and it did exactly what I needed to.