# UIWebView memory issues

Tags: iphone, memory-management, uiwebview

I am playing youtube videos on a UIWebView which appears as a modalViewController subview (flip transition). Everything works fine, even though the UIWebView is released, I still receive memory warnings after a few repeated selection of this modalViewController.

I have added my UIWebView programmatically inside ViewDidLoad. Inside `viewDidDisappear` I check for `[UIWebView retainCount]` and if greater than 1, perform the following steps:

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses]; 
[self.webView removeFromSuperview];
self.webView.delegate = nil;
self.webView = nil;

NSLog(@"[self.webView retainCount] %d", [self.webView retainCount]);
```

I am running my code on xCode 3.2.5, iOS 4.2.

Appreciate all you help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are approaching the memory management problem in the wrong way. Checking the retainCount is a valid debugging technique if you know what you are doing. It is not, however, a memory management tool. In your particular case, if the UIWebView is being displayed it will always have retain count > 1. The superview will have a retain on it thus making the "if" useless.

If the webView property is well defined (i.e. noatomic, retain) the statement:

```
 self.webView = nil;
```

should release the webView. A common mistake is to initialize the property with:

```
self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
```

This is likely to introduce a leak if the webView is defined as "retain". The correct way is

```
self.webView = [[[UIWebView alloc] init] autorelease];
```

If you can't display your controller several times without running out of memory you have a memory leak. Use Instruments (Leaks in particular) to find hte objects what are note being released properly. [This is a good tutorial](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/04/02/cocoa-tutorial-fixing-memory-leaks-with-instruments/).

Be careful in keeping your retains and releases balanced and check for leaks.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually, I did initialize webview as follows:self.webView = [[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease]; Through Instruments, I am unable to detect any leak on view dismissal. But the control reaches didReceiveMemoryWarning method with Level 1 warning and the app crashes.

Comment: @techenthusiast Have you found the solution It will be very useful if you post the solution!!! Same warning repeated and crashed in mycase am using four webviews loading images

Answer (score 0):

Your problem will be related to this:
[Is it possible to prevent an NSURLRequest from caching data or remove cached data following a request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405151/is-it-possible-to-prevent-an-nsurlrequest-from-caching-data-or-remove-cached-data)

Scroll down to my answer for an extension of the accepted answer - i had this problem for days and it's now resolved!