# Clear NSURLConnection cache

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlcache

Is there a way to clear NSURLConnection cache?

I used that to download some strings but I keep getting the same strings even though I changed that from my server.

Comment: see [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405151/is-it-possible-to-prevent-an-nsurlrequest-from-caching-data-or-remove-cached-dat

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can clear the cache explicitly using:

obj-c

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

swift

```
 URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
```

Answer (score 15):

You specify cache policy when you create your NSURLRequest object. Set the `cachePolicy` property to `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData` or use the initWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval: initializer. See [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Concepts/CachePolicies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001843-BAJEAIEE) on cache policy.

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: Clearly this is a better way to use (or not use) a cache than removing all cached responses, so this has a lot to do with the question don't you think?

Answer (score 2):

Add one random number at the end of file name

Like `abc.pdf?rand=10023`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way from official Apple pages that might help. Just read the short and informative answer in the link.

[**TLS Session Cache**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1727/_index.html)

Answer (score -4):

I had same issue, no matter what I do I will keep getting old data from web.
I did a simple solution. I made a php script. This script reads the data . now I access this php script instead of the data file and I am good to go.