# NSURLRequest produce different result than HTTP proxy client

Tags: ios, caching, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I send the same HTTP message from a HTTP proxy client and with `NSURLRequest` + `NSURLConnection`, and get back different result. It is an authentication request. From HTTP proxy authentication request is accepted, sending from app not. Why? Accepted means after redirection HTML will contains no `Oops` substring.

[image]

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.swisshttp.weact.ch/en/user/login")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

let email2 = (viewController!.email.text as NSString).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("@", withString: "%40")
let str = "name=\(email2)&pass=\(viewController!.password.text)&form_id=user_login" as NSString
let d = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
if let d2 = d {
    request.HTTPBody = d2
    let urlConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self)
}
```

## UPDATE

I have put @teamnorge's code below into playground and into an empty Single View Application project. Returned HTML in project contains the `Oops` substring, code used in playground not containes it, any idea what is going on, why same request produce different HTML result? I get `failed` message also from iOS device and from simulator too.

## UPDATE

Removed `NSURLRequest` cache like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/405896/239219) recommended, but still not works as expected. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14832400/239219).

## UPDATE

Tried to remove all the credentials like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1536425/239219), but didn't help, no credential was found.

Comment: i'd probably remove your email/password from the screenshot if i was you

Comment: one might test authentication request, it was on purpose

Comment: thanks your help, issue was different, two different url was called :-(

Answer (score 2):

It looks like when you receive HTTP 302 and new Location URL, iOS does automatically fetch the page by this URL, so I guess your response is in fact the HTML content of the redirection page. Please verify.

**UPDATE:**

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.swisshttp.weact.ch/en/user/login")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
let str = "name=kukodajanos%40icloud.com&pass=jelszo&form_id=user_login" as  NSString
let d = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
request.HTTPBody = d
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue:     NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()) { response, maybeData, error in
   if let data = maybeData {
       let contents = NSString(data:data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
       println(contents)

            if contents!.rangeOfString("Oops").length == 0 {

                println("success")
            } else {
                println("failed")
            }
   } else {
       println(error.localizedDescription)
   }
}

XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely()
```

Comment: partly you are right, iOS automatically redirects request, but the resulted page is not the same what I get in proxy client, iOS will return with failed authentication message, proxy with success message

Comment: I took the liberty to use your credentials and post a data from my playground, the only difference is that web login redirects to /challenge and ios login redirects to /user the rest seems to be ok, see my code in the post above.

Comment: used your code, and found a really weird effect, in playground it returns `success` but in app it returns `failed`, any idea why?

Comment: @János, it's quite strange, but then you may change the `queue` you are going to run your url request on from `current` to `main`.  `NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()` and add `dispatch_main()` to your main function, do you see any differences? It's not a real answer, just to comprehend what's wrong to find a solution.