# NSData Retaining Old Value -iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using the following code to generate and parse the XML.
The method `[self checksigninSucess];` is called and the `UITextField` values are set while pressing a "Sign IN" button.

```
-(void)checksigninSucess{

NSString* content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.anball/login_check.php?email=%@&password=%@",emailField.text,passwordField.text];

NSData *xml = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:content]];

NSLog(@"URLXML %@",[NSURL URLWithString:content]);

self.parser=[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:xml];
[self.parser setDelegate:self];
[self.parser parse];
[self.parser release];
self.parser=nil;
}
```

But my problem is that `NSData` holds the values which I enter in the text fields for the first time only. When I press the "Sign In" button for the second time with different email and password , `NSData` holds the same URL it generated before.
How can I clear the values held by `NSData` for the next try.

Comment: Are you sure the content string is different the second time? Maybe you are not setting the text field values right?

Comment: Print the log of your text field

Comment: NOP!!When i print the URL ([NSURL URLWithString:content]) in console it gives the modified URL but not the NSData!!

Comment: refer this link for clear caching http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405151/is-it-possible-to-prevent-an-nsurlrequest-from-caching-data-or-remove-cached-dat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need to use NSData? Use NSString instead, as follows.

```
self.parser=[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:content]];

[self.parser setDelegate:self];
[self.parser parse];
[self.parser release];
self.parser=nil;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this line instead, to prevent Caching of data

```
NSData *xml = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:content] options:NSDataReadingUncached error:nil];
```

Using second variant of function

```
+ (id)dataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)aURL options:(NSDataReadingOptions)mask error:(NSError **)errorPtr
```

See NSDataReadingOptions masks

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-307810

Comment: please, try to describe how exactly it `does not work` and use less of  exclamation marks. We can't help you without you taking part.