# What's useage of iOS app Cache.db in Library caches path?

Tags: ios

I found in iOS simulator, there is a file named Cache.db in Library caches path.

There are some tables in the db:

```
sqlite3 Cache.db 
SQLite version 3.7.5
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .table
cfurl_cache_blob_data       cfurl_cache_response      
cfurl_cache_receiver_data   cfurl_cache_schema_version
```

I want to know what does it do? And how can we make use of this db?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That is used by [`NSURLCache`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It is automatically used when you create a [`NSURLRequest`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003762) unless you specify that you do not want to use cache.

Comment: To add to rckones point you do not need to do anything in particular to use this cache. I believe it caches specific URL requests so that if you requested host.com/webservice/1 and later requested the same exact string it would load almost instantly.

Comment: To disable request caching: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405151/is-it-possible-to-prevent-an-nsurlrequest-from-caching-data-or-remove-cached-dat

Comment: Is this file cleared when the app is closed or something?

Comment: @atuljangra No Cache.db file will not be cleared automatically. You need to code for that to happen.