# Does NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData work in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, ios7, nsurl

Good evening! I'm hoping someone out there can help me out with a problem I'm seeing.

Ever since iOS 7 was rolled out the following call does NOT work:

`NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:60];`

Whenever I update the page pointed to by `url` above it pulls old content - even if I reboot the device. This problem is seen by multiple (all maybe) users of my app.

Something changed between iOS 6 and iOS 7. Does anyone have any pointers on how to reliably pull a remote file (HTML in this cases) while ignoring any and all caches? Seems like the way I WAS using is not longer working/supported.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up having to use the "timestamp" solution found in this post:

[NSURLConnection is returning old data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695023/nsurlconnection-is-returning-old-data)

Answer (score 4):

According to the `NSURLRequest` headers, `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData` is unimplemented, so I wouldn't rely on it. You may want to use `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData` and try to avoid the server cache on your server side.

```
enum
{
    NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy = 0,

    NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData = 1,
    NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData = 4, // Unimplemented
    NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData,

    NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad = 2,
    NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad = 3,

    NSURLRequestReloadRevalidatingCacheData = 5, // Unimplemented
};
typedef NSUInteger NSURLRequestCachePolicy;
```

Comment: Changing to `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData` does not work. How do you recommend avoiding the "server cache on your server side?" Is there some way to invalidate the phone AND server caches?