# NSURLConnection, login successfull with wrong credentials

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cookies, authentication, nsurlconnection

I am using NSURLConnection to connect with a server, using a GET request. To login I am sending a GET request with url of the form

```
http://<myUserName>:<myPassword>@my.serverurl.com/user/login
```

an example URL will be

```
http://someusername:somepass@www.google.com/user/login
```

When I login for the first time, and I pass the correct username and password, I am able to successfully login, and if I pass incorrect username  or password I get a response from server  saying my username and password is incorrect.. All is well then

**But when I login with correct username/password, get into my home page. There I logout to go back to login screen. Now I enter incorrect username and password and try to login, I am getting response login is successfull..This is my problem.**

That means all my subsequent login requests return successfull with incorrect username and password. I checked the same url (correct and incorrect) with the browser and there everything is working as it should be.

This is the code I am using to login

```
-(void)postRequest{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request    =   [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ; 
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:
              @"http://myusername:mypass@my.serverurl.com/user/login"]]; 
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
//    [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];   ==> I tried without this first

    loginRequestConnection  =   [[CustomURLConnection alloc]
                                      initCustomURLWithRequest:request 
                                      delegate:self 
                                      withTAG:LOGIN_REQUEST_CONNECTION];
    [request release];
}
```

Now CustomURLConnection is nothing but a subclass of NSURLConnection and added a tag to identify between multiple connection requests in the delegate

```
@interface CustomURLConnection : NSURLConnection{
}
@property()NSInteger tag;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData *receivedData;

-(id)initCustomURLWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request delegate:(id)delegate withTAG:(NSInteger)tagInt;
@end
```

I think the problem is NSURLConnection request is storing the cookie somewhere and reusing them to subsequent requests. That is why I added

```
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
```

to the code. But with or without that problem persist. So any other suggestion to what is causing this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using this 
`initWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval:` and set `cache policy` to `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData`

Try adding this delegate method.

```
 - (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse {   
return nil; 
}
```

Ensure that this method is called.

Use `NSURLCredentialStorage`  and `removeCredential` to erase your cache for credentials that are stored by `NSURLConnection`.

[Please check this answer as well.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1536425/642375)

Hope that works

Comment: tried that..But still no luck..I am still able to login with incorrect username/pass..

Comment: Once reset your simulator or if you are working in device, delete your app once, also remove cookies from memory then try again.

Comment: Tried on both simulator and device. simulator reseted, removed app from device, cleared cookies on logout and tried again..Still no luck..Was thinking of the same steps when you posted the above comment..

Comment: I got it working, it was the problem with credentials. Can you please edit your answer with the answer in the link so that I can accept it..

Comment: Happy to help :)  U can accept this as well, since it helped you. No need of again including the code that is there in the link, Yet I added summary of that link