# Stop NSURLRequest writing to cache

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlrequest, appkit, nsurlrequestcachepolicy

I have an iOS app that sends hundreds of HTTP requests per second using NSURLRequest. It's always over WiFi so performance is fine, and the content is different for every response so I've disabled caching via `NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData`:

```
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL,
      cachePolicy: .ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 0.1)
```

However, `NSURLRequest` is still writing the data to disk — hundreds of megabytes in just a few minutes.

This is especially concerning since my app is for data monitoring and may be left running for several hours at a time — and NSURLRequest is writing to the disk hundreds of times per second... I'm concerned flash memory can wear out under these conditions, even though I assume it has wear levelling.

How can I stop `NSURLRequest` from writing cache data to disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSURLRequest`'s cache policy only controls if and how the cache will be read, not whether downloaded data will be written.

If you're using `NSURLRequest` with `NSURLSession`, implement the 
`URLSession(_:dataTask:willCacheResponse:completionHandler:)` method in your delegate, and call the completionHandler with a nil argument.

A similar delegate call works if you're using `NSURLConnection`; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405151/is-it-possible-to-prevent-an-nsurlrequest-from-caching-data-or-remove-cached-dat) for details.

Comment: Thanks. This required changing one line of code to about 40 lines of code — the block based API for sending a request cannot be used if you have a delegate, and the delegate API requires doing stuff like creating an NSMutableData object and incrementally appending to it until you get a finished message. Seems like there should be an easier way. :-/