# How to clean cache when use NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy in webview

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, cache-control

I need some help...

I use`NSURLRequest *request =
      [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.xxx.com/xx.html"]];
  [webView1 loadRequest:request];`
The www.xxx.com/xx.html changed last day,but it also show the old content.How can I show the new content without upload a new App to AppStore.
I find that the Default values for cache policy is : NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy.

How can I do reload this in server.

Thanks very much!

Comment: try this :   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405151/is-it-possible-to-prevent-an-nsurlrequest-from-caching-data-or-remove-cached-dat

Comment: @johny kumar It also doesn't for me. The app is in AppStore now, I can't revise code anymore... too badly!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this it will help you

```
[webView1 stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML = \"\";"];

NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]];
[urlRequest setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];

[webView1 loadRequest:urlRequest];
```