# How to secure cache.db file in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'd like to secure *cache.db* file on iPhone. Now when I install my App and connect the iPhone to my Mac, I'm able to see *cache.db* file in the apps file structure and I'm able to read the file contents that basically contains requests and responses. I Applied NoCatch with HTTP client object. But not it makes no difference.

```
HttpClientObj.DefaultRequestHeaders.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue 
                                                       { 
                                                           NoCache = true 
                                                       };
```

Comment: Do you mean `Cache.db`? If so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39942973/4984832

Comment: I want to achieve the same thing with Xamarin, I think the above solution is for Objective C.

Comment: Yes if it is possible or please suggest me any other solution in c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translate [the solution here with SWIFT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39942973/10539446) into c#:

To prevent request and parameters being written to the `Cache.db` iOS

If you are using `NSUrlSession` :

```
    var configuration = NSUrlSessionConfiguration.DefaultSessionConfiguration;
    configuration.URLCache = new NSUrlCache(0,0,"");

    NSUrlSession seeion = NSUrlSession.FromConfiguration(configuration);
```

Or set at a global `NSUrlCache` level:

```
    NSUrlCache.SharedCache = new NSUrlCache(0,0,"");
```

**Update:**

You can use native handler when creating `HttpClient`:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        HttpClient httpClient;

        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
        {
            var configuration = NSUrlSessionConfiguration.DefaultSessionConfiguration;
            configuration.URLCache = new NSUrlCache(0, 0, "");

            NSUrlSessionHandler handler = new NSUrlSessionHandler(configuration);
            httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
        }else if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
        {
            AndroidClientHandler handler = new AndroidClientHandler();
            httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
        }

        //...your request
    }
```

Remember to Add reference to `Xamarin.iOS.dll` and `Mono.Android.dll`.

Comment: hey Jack, I am not using NSUrl while making a HTTPClient Request simply passing url in string format in httpClient.PostAsync(url, content). will your above solution work for this? Or suggest me any other way to achieve this.

Comment: @AbhishekMaurya Is your project a Xamarin.forms project or a Xamarin.iOS project?

Comment: @AbhishekMaurya You can have a try with my updated answer. Use Native handler.

Comment: sorry, I mentioned it Xamarin.ios but its Xamarin.forms project

Comment: That's ok, you can also use Native handler in xamarin.forms project.

Comment: I am not able to put Native handler code into the shared part. getting a compile error.

Comment: @AbhishekMaurya What  compile error are you getting?

Comment: @AbhishekMaurya You can mark this answer which will help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score -1):

CacheControl HeaderValue works me

```
System.Net.Http.HttpClient httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
 httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue { NoCache = true };
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.cachecontrolheadervalue.nocache?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Http_Headers_CacheControlHeaderValue_NoCache)